# Is Crystal Biome still available?

Tags: starbound

I remember that I once found on a planet, deep below, very near the final lava level, a small Crystal cave. It was a very beautiful place to play around.

In the actual version, is this minibiome still available?
If it is, in which kind of planet can I find it?

Comment: If you found out that an answer was correct, please mark it accordingly.

Comment: The wikia is a bit outdated which makes me afraid the info is incorrect, and I couldn't find any crystal yet, so, I will check a few more Lava planets, if I find so I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Crystal biome still available?

**Yes.**

There is no reference of the Crystal Biome in the changelog to begin with so it should be there.

> If it is, in which kind of planet can I find it?

According to the [Starbound Wikia](http://starbound.wikia.com/wiki/Crystal_Biome):

> <strike>The Crystal Biome occurs on the surface of magma planets and
>   minibiomes.</strike>

So be sure to check there.

---

So, as it turns out the Wikia is a bit outdated. The correct answer would be:

> The Crystal Biome occurs on the surface of **volcanic terrain planets**
>   and minibiomes.

according to @DarkHyudrA's input.

Comment: OK so I checked it. It's actually "volcanic terrain planets", and not magma ones. Even if they have almost no terrain, I went to a big magma planet, walked to one direction until I came back to spawn position, and I didn't found a single crystal. While on a small "volcanic terrain", I found a quite good amount of it. Please update your answer so it can reflect the actual info.